# Is it possible to build multiple configurations at the same time in visual basic express edition 2008?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, msbuild, .net-3.5

As far as I know, I can't build multiple configs at once within a visual studio express edition, but I have tried with msbuild and a vbproj file, with limited success:

```
<Target Name="Build">
  <MSBuild Projects="solution1.sln" Properties="Configuration=Debug;Platform=Any CPU" />
  <MSBuild Projects="solution1.sln" Properties="Configuration=Release;Platform=Any CPU" />
  <MSBuild Projects="solution1.sln" Properties="Configuration=Custom;Platform=Any CPU" />
</Target>
```

This happily compiles the 1st two standard configurations, but fails at Custom with the message:

"The specified configuration "Custom|Any CPU" is invalid. Please specify a valid ..."

Note that the Custom configuration compiles fine within visual studio.

Any ideas why it's failing?

Comment: Is "Custom" and solution configuration or are they configurations on each of the individual projects in your solution?

Comment: What heavyd said.  Can you show the top of your Solution1.sln file where the options for Configuration and Platform are validated?

Comment: @Hans, It's self explanetary unless I'm missing something. After making a change, I want to recompile all 6 of my configs at once instead of: Select Config1/ Compile/ Wait..., Select Config2/ Compile/ Wait..., Select Config6/ Compile.

Comment: @heavyd & Cheeso. I think you've pointed me in the direction of my error. It looks like I may have set up the different configurations in a solution I was using for testing (which included my core project), but at the command line I was pointing to my core solution, which includes just the default debug and release. I'll check that out ...